# google script type error is not a function in date function

Tags: date, google-apps-script

can someone help me figure what's wrong with my logic?, i'm new using google script app and stuck around a week and got this error

Error message:

> TypeError: d1.getTime is not a function (inDays)

```
var DateDiff = {    
              inDays: function(d1, d2) {
                var t2 = d2.getTime();
                var t1 = d1.getTime();
                Logger.log("t1" + t1)
                return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000)+1);
              }
            }

var dateStr = data[m][xMonth].toString() // the value here is =>1/10/2022
var todayDate = new Date();

if(dateStr.toString().includes('/')){

              var yearA = '20'+dateStr.substring(6, 8)
             
              var monthA = +dateStr.substring(3, 5)
              if(monthA.toString() != '11' || monthA.toString() != '12') monthA = '0'+monthA
             
              var dayA = +dateStr.substring(0, 2)
              var tempDate = yearA + monthA + dayA
             

              var Ryear = +tempDate.substring(0, 4)
              var Rmonth = +tempDate.substring(4, 6)
              var Rday = +tempDate.substring(6, 8)

              var newDate = new Date(Ryear, Rmonth - 1, Rday)//because month start from 0
         
              var realDueDate = DateDiff.inDays(todayDate, newDate) // error here in var newDate 
            }
```

Comment: It looks like d1 is not a Date() object

Comment: You must be doing something with `todayDate` that you didn't show us here.

Comment: thanks for help @Cooper before, that i want to know why i got that error is not a function, as you can see the var 'realDueDate' in very bottom of my code, d1 is todayDate var, im still dont understand, and sorry for my bad english, lol

Comment: @TheMaster there's todayDate, i already show in the middle code, before if function

Comment: I can see that. What I'm saying is you're doing something  to it which you're not showing to us. Why don't you reproduce it here in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) by mocking the `data` array? See [mcve]

Comment: You generally are getting that error because the method does not exist for an object of the wrong type.  But it's hard to debug your code for you unless you build us a [mcve]  what's interesting about the process of building us a good [mcve] is that most of the type it results in you figuring out the problem on your own and never asking us a question at all.  But most people insist on posting their original code and avoid doing the work of creating a [mcve] and if the solution is not obvious to us it often results in an unanswered question.

Comment: thanks for your help, im try for new solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myFunk() {
  const D2 = new Date();
  const D1 = new Date(D2.getFullYear(),D2.getMonth() - 2,D2.getDate());
  var DateDiff = {
    d1:D1,d2:D2,
    inDays: function () {
      let t2 = this.d2.getTime();
      let t1 = this.d1.getTime();
      return parseInt((t2 - t1) / (24 * 3600 * 1000) + 1);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(DateDiff.inDays());
}

Execution log
10:58:41 AM Notice  Execution started
10:58:39 AM Info    62.0
10:58:41 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: this application is for read excel file from google sheet, or can someone help me to figure, how to read date String from cell google sheet using my function in above?
thanks guys for helping me

in excel cell example: 12/24/2021

im trying to compare that cell for dueDate with new Date() function in GAS(google apps script)

Comment: what i want is
from google sheet excel 
x=12/1/2021


in google apps script
b = new Date(x) 
a = new Date()
and using inDays(a,b)

Comment: 'var DateDiff = {    
              inDays: function(d1, d2) {
                var t2 = d2.getTime();
                var t1 = d1.getTime();
                Logger.log("t1" + t1)
                return parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000)+1);
              }
            }

var newDate = new Date(dateStr)
              x = Date.parse(newDate)
              y = new Date()
              Logger.log("pubdate: " + x)
              var realDueDate = DateDiff.inDays(y, x)
'

Comment: if your date is in MM/dd/yyyy format then new Date(MM/dd/yyyy) constructor  will create a javascript Date() object.